# How to activate key down when button is clicked in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, keydown

I have a button and textbox in WPF application. Textbox has a string "Hello you guy", caret at the beginning (before **Hello**). When user clicks the button, I want my application to activate KeyDown event with Control+Right, so caret in my textbox moves to before the word **you**. When user clicks the button again, caret move to before the word **guy**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the caret position using CaretIndex property of a TextBox. Please bear in mind that this is not a DependencyProperty. Nevertheless, you may still set it in XAML like this:

```
<TextBox Text="123" CaretIndex="{x:Static System:Int32.MaxValue}" />
```

Please remember to set CaretIndex after Text property or else it will not work. Thus it probably won't work if you bind to Text. You can simply use code-behind like this also.

```
txtbox.CaretIndex = 12;
```

Try this!

```
var text = this.textbox.Text.SubString(this.textbox.CaretIndex);
int newIndex = text.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
if (newIndex > 0)
    this.textbox.CaretIndex = newIndex;
```

Comment: You could of course create an AttachedProperty. But it would only support one way binding.

Comment: Thanks. But I have problem with Japanese (no white space) so I can't find index to set CaretIndex.

Comment: It's quite imppssible to do it unless you have some common logic behind the japanese words like all words are of same length or the beginnibg of a new word is yhe same letter.  If so we could identify that specific condition and write code to set the caret brush according to that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, normally when you press a button, the focus will be removed from other controls, and given to the button. This is also the normal expected behavior. Of course, this can be changed via code, but you should have a good reason to break this convention.

Secondly, it might be easier to simply manipulate with that textbox directly, from the button's `Click` event.

```
// Inside Click event for the button
this.textbox.Focus(); // Make sure textbox gets back focus

var text = this.textbox.Text.SubString(this.textbox.CaretIndex);
int newIndex = text.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
if (newIndex > 0)
    this.textbox.CaretIndex = newIndex;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have problem with Japanese (no white space) so I can't find index of white space to set CaretIndex.

Comment: @AlexHuynh So what's the behavior that you expect when Japanese input is received? Auto-detect particles and jump particle-to-particle?

Comment: I have a Japanese sentence e.g. "日本の医療政策の概要と基本情報". If user presses Control+Right at the beginning, I want to get "の". If user presses again, caret moves to before "医" and I want to get "医療". In other word, I want to get current stop and next stop, in order to get next stop, I have to trigger that key press (Control+Right) again.

Comment: @AlexHuynh As far as I see, there is no simple way to do this. I know you want to do something similar to what IME is doing, where user keys in a whole sentence of characters (hiragana), and the IME groups them into phrases. Doing this means that you must have a dictionary database to compare against, which is probably an overkill to implement. Personally I think it's fine to do it without this function - afterall a Japanese "word" tends to be within 5 characters long, so it won't be as terrible as western languages where 2 words away can mean pressing left/right for 30 repetitions.